# Javascript, using session variable for switch statement

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not sure how to do this but i'd like to use the given value which comes from an session variable inside a javascript switch statement to make the hidden divs visible if the value matches the case. So far I got this.

The hidden divs which are inside a list which is inside another div. Situated on page 1.

```
 <html>

 <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><div style="display:none;" id="div1"> <a href="#">page 1</a></div></li>
            <li><div style="display:none;" id="div2"> <a href="#">page 2</a></div></li>
            <li><div style="display:none;" id="div3"> <a href="#">page 3</a></div></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

The retrieval of the value from the session. Situated on page 1.

```
<input type="hidden" id="ID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ID'];?>" />
</html>
```

The javascript, situated on page 2.

```
var sessionID =  document.getElementById("ID").value;

$(document).ready(function() {
switch(sessionID) {
    case 2002:
        $("#div1").show();
        break;
    case 2003:
        $("#div2").show();
        break;
    case 2004:
        $("#div3").show();
        break;
}
});
</script>
```

The issue I have is that it's not working and I'm not sure why. Any help is greatly appriciated.

My page 2 setup goes as follows.

```
<?php include "header.php";?>

<div id="content">
Some random text
</div>
<script>The script goes in here</script>

<?php include "footer.php";?>
```

edited for some more clarity. Since things still aren't working as intended.

Comment: Yes,  i used alert to display the saved sessionID. It displays 2002,2003 or 2004 depening on which of the persons I use to log in.

Comment: Used every solution though it still won't display the hidden divs. The variables are being set in JS. Would it be an issue if this is not situated on one page but two pages, since I use an include at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Match with the string case

```
case '2002':
    $("#div1").show();
    break;
case '2003':
    $("#div2").show();
    break;
case '2004':
    $("#div3").show();
    break;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wps46o99/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

`sessionID` is a `String` but the case clause contains integers. So convert sessionId to `Number`. Unary operator `+` will help us to convert it to Number, thought there are other methods too.

```
switch(+sessionID) {
   case 2002:
      $("#div1").show();
      break;
   case 2003:
      $("#div2").show();
      break;
   case 2004:
      $("#div3").show();
      break;
}
```

Other ways are `switch(Number(sessionId))` and `switch(parseInt(sessionId,10))` and to convert the case clause to Strings as in `case '2002'`

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt` function to convert the string to integer

```
var sessionID =  parseInt(document.getElementById("ID").value);
```